# The method pickImage isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart

**Error: The method 'pickImage' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePicker'.**
***How do you solve this problem, please?***
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you are using the old version of Image_picker or
you have a name conflict. Make sure to neither name your files
image_picker.dart or name your class ImagePicker.

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved. I was using this name for the class